# How do I setup a PdfReader filepath?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf, itext

This may seem like a trivial question, I would like to open an existing pdf template, edit and flatten the file, then send as an email attachment. But how do I setup PdfReader to read my file located in my Content folder (Content/Documents/PDFFile.pdf). This is what I have which gives the error "(whatever path I try).pdf not found as a file or resource".

```
       using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            //Error is here...
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("~/Content/Documents/PDFFile.pdf");

            PdfStamper formFiller = new PdfStamper(reader, ms);
            AcroFields formFields = formFiller.AcroFields;
            formFields.SetField("Name", formData.Name);
            formFields.SetField("Location", formData.Address);
            formFields.SetField("Date", DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());
            formFields.SetField("Email", formData.Email);
            formFiller.FormFlattening = true;
            formFiller.Close();

            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("to@email.com"));
            msg.From = new MailAddress("from@email.com");
            msg.Subject = "Application Form";
            msg.Body = "TEST";
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms, "Application.pdf", "application/x-pdf"));
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("10.1.1.15");
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        }
```

Any suggestions/ideas/recommendations?

Comment: Does it work if you use the absolute path?  I haven't tried, but my first guess would be that the PDFReader isn't interpreting the `~/` correctly.

Comment: I used "../", "../../" as well and still no luck

Comment: I was thinking the full local path, including the drive letter, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `Server.MapPath("/Path/Here.pdf");` or `Request.PhysicalApplicationPath("/Path/Here.pdf");`

Comment: I am not sure how you want me to do this...sorry

Comment: `PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Documents/PDFFile.pdf"));`

Comment: I thought so, but I have no reference for "Server" in the cs file for Models. So I am getting an error

Comment: I read the pdf in the controller and passed in the function. Thanks for the help guys

Comment: @soerenn Can you elaborate a little on the solution you found? I am having the same problem. Thx.

Comment: If you're not running a web-application, then you should probably use System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory and then do something like this: Path.GetFullPath(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/test.pdf")